# What is the fastest way to determine if a double is functionally zero

Tags: c++, performance

I'm working on refactoring some code for performance that deals with lots of floating point computations (according to [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) about 90% of our time is spent in this function, so optimizations are good); however, if we have a situation where `x` is effectively zero then we can just assign zero and move on. Previously we were doing the following (assuming in-lined functions):

```
if (std::fabs(a - b) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) {
   // do things
}
```

Where `b = 0.0` in most cases. Whereas now I'm shifting the following pattern when I know that `b` is zero:

```
if (std::abs(a) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) {
  // do things
}
```

Which seems to save us a couple cycles. However, is there more that can be done to speed things up, or is this more or less the threshold?

Comment: b is near to zero? - b  ḿissing?

Comment: `std::fpclassify()` doesn't deal in epsilon, only in +/-0.

Comment: @user207421: It's probably not *exactly* the same thing, but it would be a way to exclude subnormal numbers (numbers so close to zero that they couldn't be represented with normal `double` precision rules if not for the special category reserved for near zero numbers). `switch` on `std::fpclassify`, and treat `FP_ZERO` and `FP_SUBNORMAL` is being equivalent (both of them "effectively" zero).

Comment: Do you want to test just a single value, where you have no influence how it was produced? Is `// do things` a lot of code, or is it worth to make the code branch-free?

Comment: Are you profiling optimised code?  If so, profilers can get confused and give misleading results at the micro level.  Also, I assume you have put your function in a header file so that the compiler can inline it.

Comment: If you consider anything below epsilon as 0, you are not really doing **floating** point, closer to fixed point. Is there a way you could just use integers instead?

Comment: Re: “calculating probabilities … has to be floating point” — not necessary. Probabilities range from 0 to 1. If you need four digits of precision, multiply everything by 10000 and use integers. That’s obviously oversimplified, but it illustrates the basic idea.

Comment: @rjzii With the amount of information given, it is impossible to give you suggestions how you can implement this faster. It is not unlikely that you could join multiple comparisons into one, or execute some code branch-free. A definite answer requires much more context though. The paper you linked to does not give any obvious hints where you would like to branch, and anyways, you should put all relevant information into the question itself.

Comment: @rjzii "The fastest way", really depends on how you generate the number, what you do with the result, how often your numbers are functionally zero, etc. And of course also on your hardware, e.g., with SIMD you can determine the zero-ness of multiple inputs at once. If that helps in your can't be answered without more context.

Comment: Also, "the fastest" could mean highest throughput or lowest latency. And both could be either on average or the worst case -- e.g. sometimes it may help to get an answer in 2 cycles 99% of the time, but sometimes spend 20 extra cycles (for example you can test `if(fabs(x)<2.0)` with a single bit-test, which depending on your data may or may not rule out a lot of cases). Or it may be better to always use 5 cycles (completely made-up numbers for illustration).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's about as efficient as it's going to get. With optimizations enabled, on an x86-64 system, the resulting assembly for that `if` is:

1. A `movsd` (to load the value of `epsilon` from global constant memory to a register; the function becomes just a constant to load)
2. An `andpd` (to mask away the negative sign bit in the `double` being checked, that's all `std::abs` has to do when inlined)
3. A `comisd` (to compare the two registers)
4. A `ja` (the actual conditional branch)

The first three instructions change to the `v` prefixed form if compiled for more modern chips (I guess the new versions are a titch more efficient when available), but otherwise don't change. That's about as cheap as it gets. I suppose in theory if you were doing this a *lot*, vectorization might let you do the same work for multiple values with fewer instructions, but:

1. The compiler might figure this out on its own, and
2. If it doesn't, I'd wait for profiling to show this is a bottleneck before worrying further

As far as I can tell, any solution based on `std::fpclassify` (where you want `FP_ZERO` and `FP_SUBNORMAL` to be considered equivalent), e.g.:

```
switch (std::fpclassify(a)) {
case FP_SUBNORMAL:
case FP_ZERO:
    // do things
    break;
}
```

involve the same `andpd` instruction, plus *three* `comisd` (or `ucomisd`) instructions, and *three* conditional jumps; two additional compares and conditional branches are almost certainly worse than loading a single constant.

Answer (score 1):

Another optimization you can consider is discarding more cases:

```
constexpr float near_zero_limit = 0.01f;

if (std::fabs(a - b) < near_zero_limit )
```

It's not that the test is faster is that there are more cases where you don't do the rest of the work. I don't know your algorithm and if this makes sense for your computations, but you can search for the largest `near_zero_limit` where it's acceptable to you to consider the final result effectively zero or imperceptible from zero and if that brings more performance.